# Multiple Processes getting stopped with error "Resource temporarily unavailable" and "can't fork" resulting in crash

Tags: server, cron, docker, logs

We are running a script on Dell Edge gateway 3002 to send data to cloud, but after running for 4-5 days the gateway becomes unresponsive(hanged state) and can't be pinged. The gateway has  Ubuntu 18.04.3 on it . After checking the logs we get multiple "can't fork/exec" and "Resource temporary unavailable" errors related to cron,docker,..etc

These are the syslogs from the day of crash :

```
    Line 4613: Aug 19 10:23:12 80LSN42 snapd[885]: stateengine.go:108: state ensure error: cannot refresh snap-declaration for "core": Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/99T7MUlRhtI3U0QFgl5mXXESAiSwt776?max-format=3: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
    Line 6546: Aug 19 12:03:06 80LSN42 snapd[885]: stateengine.go:108: state ensure error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
    Line 6947: Aug 19 12:23:06 80LSN42 snapd[885]: stateengine.go:108: state ensure error: cannot refresh snap-declaration for "core": Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/99T7MUlRhtI3U0QFgl5mXXESAiSwt776?max-format=3: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
    Line 13371: Aug 19 17:34:45 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T09:34:45Z [ERR!] - server connection error: (unknown)
    Line 13372: Aug 19 17:34:45 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T09:34:45Z [ERR!] - error writing a body to connection: Broken pipe (os error 32)
    Line 13372: Aug 19 17:34:45 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T09:34:45Z [ERR!] - error writing a body to connection: Broken pipe (os error 32)
    Line 13377: Aug 19 17:34:48 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T09:34:48Z [ERR!] - server connection error: (unknown)
    Line 13378: Aug 19 17:34:48 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T09:34:48Z [ERR!] - error writing a body to connection: Broken pipe (os error 32)
    Line 13378: Aug 19 17:34:48 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T09:34:48Z [ERR!] - error writing a body to connection: Broken pipe (os error 32)
    Line 14386: Aug 19 18:23:03 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T10:23:03Z [ERR!] - server connection error: (unknown)
    Line 14387: Aug 19 18:23:03 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T10:23:03Z [ERR!] - error writing a body to connection: Broken pipe (os error 32)
    Line 14387: Aug 19 18:23:03 80LSN42 iotedged[8469]: 2019-08-19T10:23:03Z [ERR!] - error writing a body to connection: Broken pipe (os error 32)
    Line 15240: Aug 19 19:03:06 80LSN42 snapd[885]: stateengine.go:108: state ensure error: cannot refresh snap-declaration for "core": Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/99T7MUlRhtI3U0QFgl5mXXESAiSwt776?max-format=3: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
    Line 15739: Aug 19 19:28:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15740: Aug 19 19:28:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15760: Aug 19 19:29:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15761: Aug 19 19:29:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15780: Aug 19 19:30:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15781: Aug 19 19:30:01 80LSN42 CRON[25697]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15799: Aug 19 19:31:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15800: Aug 19 19:31:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15818: Aug 19 19:32:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15819: Aug 19 19:32:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15843: Aug 19 19:33:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15844: Aug 19 19:33:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15871: Aug 19 19:34:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15872: Aug 19 19:34:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15892: Aug 19 19:35:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15893: Aug 19 19:35:01 80LSN42 CRON[25923]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15913: Aug 19 19:36:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15914: Aug 19 19:36:01 80LSN42 CRON[25936]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15933: Aug 19 19:37:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15934: Aug 19 19:37:01 80LSN42 CRON[25949]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15955: Aug 19 19:38:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15956: Aug 19 19:38:01 80LSN42 CRON[25974]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15975: Aug 19 19:39:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15976: Aug 19 19:39:01 80LSN42 CRON[26000]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15996: Aug 19 19:40:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 15997: Aug 19 19:40:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16016: Aug 19 19:41:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16017: Aug 19 19:41:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16036: Aug 19 19:42:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16037: Aug 19 19:42:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16055: Aug 19 19:43:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16056: Aug 19 19:43:01 80LSN42 CRON[26090]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16076: Aug 19 19:44:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16077: Aug 19 19:44:01 80LSN42 CRON[26107]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16096: Aug 19 19:45:01 80LSN42 cron[855]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16097: Aug 19 19:45:01 80LSN42 CRON[26124]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
    Line 16108: Aug 19 19:45:37 80LSN42 dockerd[1227]: time="2019-08-19T19:45:37.338637305+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/edgeHub/top returned error: OCI runtime state failed: runc did not terminate sucessfully: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable\nSIGABRT: abort\nPC=0x6e7ede m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610\n\ngoroutine 0 [idle]:\nruntime: unknown pc 0x6e7ede\nstack: frame={sp:0x7fff66f25ca8, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7fff667271b8,0x7fff66f261e0)\n00007fff66f25ba8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007fff66f25bb8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007fff66f25bc8:  00007f4a3d2cc000  0000000000453c50 <runtime.mmap.func1+0> \n00007fff66f25bd8:  00007fff66f25c28  00007fff66f25c38 \n00007fff66f25be8:  0000000000000040  0000000000000040 \n00007fff66f25bf8:  0000000000000001  000000006e43a318 \n00007fff66f25c08:  00000000006cde8c  0000000000d4a718 \n00007fff66f25c18:  000000000045b31e <runtime.callCgoMmap+62>  00007fff66f25c28 \n00007fff66f25c28:  00000000...
    Line 16108: Aug 19 19:45:37 80LSN42 dockerd[1227]: time="2019-08-19T19:45:37.338637305+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/edgeHub/top returned error: OCI runtime state failed: runc did not terminate sucessfully: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable\nSIGABRT: abort\nPC=0x6e7ede m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610\n\ngoroutine 0 [idle]:\nruntime: unknown pc 0x6e7ede\nstack: frame={sp:0x7fff66f25ca8, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7fff667271b8,0x7fff66f261e0)\n00007fff66f25ba8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007fff66f25bb8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007fff66f25bc8:  00007f4a3d2cc000  0000000000453c50 <runtime.mmap.func1+0> \n00007fff66f25bd8:  00007fff66f25c28  00007fff66f25c38 \n00007fff66f25be8:  0000000000000040  0000000000000040 \n00007fff66f25bf8:  0000000000000001  000000006e43a318 \n00007fff66f25c08:  00000000006cde8c  0000000000d4a718 \n00007fff66f25c18:  000000000045b31e <runtime.callCgoMmap+62>  00007fff66f25c28 \n00007fff66f25c28:  00000000...
    Line 16113: Aug 19 19:45:38 80LSN42 dockerd[1227]: time="2019-08-19T19:45:38.006022597+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/edgeHub/top returned error: OCI runtime state failed: runc did not terminate sucessfully: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable\nSIGABRT: abort\nPC=0x6e7ede m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610\n\ngoroutine 0 [idle]:\nruntime: unknown pc 0x6e7ede\nstack: frame={sp:0x7ffed95c0af8, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7ffed8dc2008,0x7ffed95c1030)\n00007ffed95c09f8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007ffed95c0a08:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007ffed95c0a18:  00007f6565ba1000  0000000000453c50 <runtime.mmap.func1+0> \n00007ffed95c0a28:  00007ffed95c0a78  00007ffed95c0a88 \n00007ffed95c0a38:  0000000000000040  0000000000000040 \n00007ffed95c0a48:  0000000000000001  000000006e43a318 \n00007ffed95c0a58:  00000000006cde8c  0000000000d4a718 \n00007ffed95c0a68:  000000000045b31e <runtime.callCgoMmap+62>  00007ffed95c0a78 \n00007ffed95c0a78:  00000000...
    Line 16113: Aug 19 19:45:38 80LSN42 dockerd[1227]: time="2019-08-19T19:45:38.006022597+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/edgeHub/top returned error: OCI runtime state failed: runc did not terminate sucessfully: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable\nSIGABRT: abort\nPC=0x6e7ede m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610\n\ngoroutine 0 [idle]:\nruntime: unknown pc 0x6e7ede\nstack: frame={sp:0x7ffed95c0af8, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7ffed8dc2008,0x7ffed95c1030)\n00007ffed95c09f8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007ffed95c0a08:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007ffed95c0a18:  00007f6565ba1000  0000000000453c50 <runtime.mmap.func1+0> \n00007ffed95c0a28:  00007ffed95c0a78  00007ffed95c0a88 \n00007ffed95c0a38:  0000000000000040  0000000000000040 \n00007ffed95c0a48:  0000000000000001  000000006e43a318 \n00007ffed95c0a58:  00000000006cde8c  0000000000d4a718 \n00007ffed95c0a68:  000000000045b31e <runtime.callCgoMmap+62>  00007ffed95c0a78 \n00007ffed95c0a78:  00000000...
    Line 16116: Aug 19 19:45:42 80LSN42 dockerd[1227]: time="2019-08-19T19:45:42.542392306+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/edgeHub/top returned error: OCI runtime state failed: runc did not terminate sucessfully: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable\nSIGABRT: abort\nPC=0x6e7ede m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610\n\ngoroutine 0 [idle]:\nruntime: unknown pc 0x6e7ede\nstack: frame={sp:0x7ffeee7dd0f8, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7ffeedfde608,0x7ffeee7dd630)\n00007ffeee7dcff8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007ffeee7dd008:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 \n00007ffeee7dd018:  00007fe86fe7d000  0000000000453c50 <runtime.mmap.func1+0> \n00007ffeee7dd028:  00007ffeee7dd078  00007ffeee7dd088 \n00007ffeee7dd038:  0000000000000040  0000000000000040 \n00007ffeee7dd048:  0000000000000001  000000006e43a318 \n00007ffeee7dd058:  00000000006cde8c  0000000000d4a718 \n00007ffeee7dd068:  000000000045b31e <runtime.callCgoMmap+62>  00007ffeee7dd078 \n00007ffeee7dd078:  00000000...
    Line 16116: Aug 19 19:45:42 80LSN42 dockerd[1227]: time="2019-08-19T19:45:42.542392306+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/edgeHub/top returned error: OCI runtime state failed: runc did not terminate sucessfully: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

These errors keep on repeating.
We also tried checking and changing the following limits:

- kernel.pid_max limit (kernel limit)
- ulimit -u (user limit)
- systemctl status cron/docker | grep Tasks (service limit)

But there was no luck!!
Please help give some insights!!

Comment: Likely hit sime process count limit. What says `ps`? Any "zombie" processes? Are these docker processes? Do you run them with `--rm`?

Comment: You said you tried changing ulimit, sysctl etc. When you decided to change pid_max_limit, I assume you did it because you saw pids were exhausted. Could you share more info what limits you found were hit before you changed them? And why changing did not help.

Comment: @xenoid thanks for replying. There are no zombie processes. Yes docker service is also running hence the docker daemon errors. i am not sure about --rm.

Comment: `--rm` makes sure your containers and their associated resources don't stay around when they terminate.

Comment: @marosg thanks for replying. Yes i changed the pid limit for exact same reason. Including pid_max_limit I changed task limit of cron and docker services , made them unlimited. Changing them did not help because I am still getting the same errors when i tested it.

Comment: @xenoid ok but then what about cron? Are you suggesting a memory leak because of docker?

Comment: Not a memory leak, but possibly getting our of open file handles. This looks like something is accumulating somewhere, and upping the limits is typically the wrong solution. What happens when the data transfer is finished? The problem is likely in your scripts and their design, so if you want further help you would have to share them with us.

Comment: @xenoid sry but I won't be able to share the scripts. Can you suggest something to explore this problem further and go in depth of it, it would be really helpful !!!